# using condition for Group_Concat

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to find all ids of which group_concat only contains 'a'.
Here is simplified table from mine.

```
╔════╦══════════════╦
║ id ║ group_concat ║
╠════╬══════════════╬
║  1 ║ a,b,b        ║
║  2 ║ a            ║
║  3 ║ a,a          ║
║  4 ║ a,a,a        ║
║  5 ║ a,b,a        ║
╚════╩══════════════╩
```

And the table below is what I want to achieve.

```
╔════╦══════════════╦
║ id ║ group_concat ║
╠════╬══════════════╬
║  2 ║ a            ║
║  3 ║ a,a          ║
║  4 ║ a,a,a        ║
╚════╩══════════════╩
```

And this is the query statement I am trying to use.

```
select id, group_concat(val)
from user
group by id
having group_concat(val) = 'a'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id, group_concat(val)
from user
group by id
having count(distinct val) = 1 and max(val) = 'a'
```